# What is the purpose of Spring Boot excluding Lombok plugin?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok

I am aware what Lombok is, it minimizes boilerplate code through the use of some annotations. Lombok generates the equivalent Java code at compile time by using Java internals [[Ref]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107197/how-does-lombok-work). Hence it does not need any explicit plugin or Maven/Gradle build phase during compile time.

On looking at the pom.xml of a Spring Boot Project, I see below plugins section and am wondering what this exclusion is about.

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 9):

Well, the problem is following: Lombok is an annotation processor, and the code generated with/by Lombok does not depend on Lombok anymore. In Maven terms that means the dependency on Lombok should have `provided` scope (in order to not include the Lombok jar into the target artifact). Unfortunately, the Spring developers have another opinion about dependencies with scope=`provided`. Please check this conversation: [Maven requires plugin version to be specified for the managed dependency spring-boot-configuration-processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70207686/maven-requires-plugin-version-to-be-specified-for-the-managed-dependency-spring/70208349#70208349)

So, your configuration explicitly removes the Lombok jar from the target artifact.